# asp.net-ajax EndRequest handler not fired

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have used aspnet ajax to show progress image on server request.
code:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            //             alert('B');
            var elem = args.get_postBackElement();
            ActivateAlertDiv('visible', 'AlertDiv', elem.value + ' processing...');
        }
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            ActivateAlertDiv('hidden', 'AlertDiv', '');
        }
        function ActivateAlertDiv(visstring, elem, msg) {
            var adiv = $get(elem);
            adiv.style.visibility = visstring;
            //                    adiv.innerHTML = msg;
        }
```

BeginRequestHandler is called and progress image is visible but  EndRequestHandler is not called. due to this progress image running continuously.